# Highlight next element of class name of last element - CSS3

Tags: html, css

Using below code, I am able to highlight the element with value 2 and 3 instead of element 3. I tried using last child and nth-last-type but didn't work as expected. Issue is with highlighting immediate next element of class - active and apply blink to both tick mark of 3 and value 3 and change of active class to change blink

No Jquery solution, as currently trying to implement using CSS3

I am trying to choose first element of class hightlight without active class using CSS only

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="steps" style="width:26%;float:left">
        <div class="stepSection">
 <table>
            <tr><td><div class="highlight active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div></td><td>1.</td><td> <span>one</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><div class="highlight active" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div></td><td>2.</td><td> <span>two</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td><div class="highlight"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div> </td><td>3.</td><td><span>three</span></td></tr>
 <tr><td><div class="highlight"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div> </td><td>3.</td><td><span>four</span></td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      </div>

  <div style="width:2%;float:left;">
          <div class="highlight active">1</div>
          <div class="highlight active">2</div>
          <div class="highlight">3</div>
          <div class="highlight">4</div>
      </div>
```

CSS3:

```
.highlight{
    color:white;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: rgb(234,116,0);
    display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.active{
    background:green;
}

@keyframes blink {
to { background: rgb(234,116,0); }
}

.active + .highlight{
color: white;
background: white;
animation: blink 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
```

Comment: kinda looks like you used the glyphicon class too many times...  Also, can you maybe clarify your question a little?  It's hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Matt, I am trying to make the next element of class active blink , if value1 element is active, blink 2 , and if value2 element , then blink 3 , in short I am trying to choose first element of class hightlight without active class using CSS only

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Jquery**
You can do it using jquery like so

```
$(".active:last").next().addClass("blink")
```

And change your css to have blink class

```
.blink {
color: white;
background: white;
animation: blink 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
```

[Working Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7pux0wq/2/)

**Method 2:**
If you want to do it only using css , you need to book keep your last element
by adding a class to the last element say `.last`

```
 <div style="width:2%;float:left;">
     <div class="highlight active">1</div>
     <div class="highlight active last">2</div>
     <div class="highlight">3</div>
     <div class="highlight">4</div>
 </div>
```

and then do you css like

```
.last + .highlight {
   color: white;
   background: white;
   animation: blink 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
```

**Method 3:**

change your css to

```
   div.active + div:not(.active){
    color: white;
    background: white;
    animation: blink 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
    }
```

Basically it finds the element which has class active before it and the next class which does not have the class active.

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7pux0wq/11/)

Comment: thanks but is it possible in CSS3 and trying to implement with CSS3 and without jquery

Comment: thanks Imprefectluck , last works but again for that I need to use jquery , on selection active changes and correspondingly changing blink. Is there any way to get the element 2 with class active and apply blink to 3

Comment: check the last one using CSS3 alone without using any jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nth-last-type you may use:

```
.highlight + .highlight:not(.active):nth-of-type(3) {
```

The snippet:

```css
.highlight {
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(234, 116, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.active {
    background: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
    to {
        background: rgb(234, 116, 0);
    }
}



.highlight + .highlight:not(.active):nth-of-type(3) {
    color: white;
    background: white;
    animation: blink 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="steps" style="width:26%;float:left">
    <div class="stepSection">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="highlight active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
                </td>
                <td>1.</td>
                <td><span>one</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="highlight active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
                </td>
                <td>2.</td>
                <td><span>two</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="highlight"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
                </td>
                <td>3.</td>
                <td><span>three</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="highlight"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
                </td>
                <td>3.</td>
                <td><span>four</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:2%;float:left;">
    <div class="highlight active">1</div>
    <div class="highlight active">2</div>
    <div class="highlight">3</div>
    <div class="highlight">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if I change active class, it doesn't work and need to add all conditions in css

Comment: yes gaetonM,  I am trying to choose first element of class hightlight without active class using CSS only